# ZF2 Directory/Namespace Model Object Location

Tags: zend-framework2

In the [zf2 database and models tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html) a path such as this leads to a directory containing my model classes:

```
module/Album/src/Album/Model
```

I have created two more classes at:

```
module/Album/src/Album/Model/AlbumRelatedClass.php
module/Album/src/Album/Model/AlbumRelatedTable.php
```

I would like to put these classes at

```
module/Album/src/AlbumRelated/Model/
```

I have created duplicates of the model classes there for the purposes of this test, unfortunately, my module config for Album tells me that it cannot find the classes at the AlbumRelated location. I have tried changing the namespaces in the AlbumRelated location to AlbumRelated\Model and directly referring to the class location (\Album\Model\AlbumRelated()) without success.

Does anyone know how I can do this? If I shouldn't be doing this, can somebody explain why? I'm also interested to know why the folder structure is Album/Model/Album (it seems redundant, and I wasn't clear on the explanation in the tutorial).

Any help given would be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that it can't find the class because you probably didn't set up the autoloader config to know about a new "AlbumRelated" namespace.  Look at what happens in `\Album\Module::getAutoloaderConfig()`.  You probably want to add a key/value pair to `namespaces` like `'AlbumRelated' => __DIR__ . '/src/AlbumRelated'`.  That will tell the autoloader where to look for classes under the AlbumRelated namespace.

That said,

> If I shouldn't be doing this, can somebody explain why?

You probably shouldn't be doing it that way.  You've got a top-level namespace called `\Album`. Then you have `\Album\Model` namespace under it.  Any models related to Albums ought to live there.  Imagine you had an entity in your system for Record Labels, so  you could associate an Album with the label that released it.  The ZF2 expectation is that you'd create a class called `\Album\Model\RecordLabel` that lived in `module/Album/src/Album/Model/RecordLabel.php`.  As long as we assume that RecordLabels are primarily related to albums, that all makes perfect sense.

Of course, you could stick RecordLabel in it's own module as well, if you had a lot of workflow around managing them.

> I'm also interested to know why the folder structure is Album/Model/Album

I assume you mean Album/src/Album.  That redundancy is to keep a nice clean [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) setup. So, the first Album is identifying the module, and the second is the top-level of the Album namespace.  This provides maximum flexibility, but isn't a hard and fast rule. See Rob Allen's recent blog post about [alternative module layouts in zf2](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/thoughts-on-module-directory-structure/) for an exploration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does that mean there would never be a folder adjacent to module/Album/src/Album such as module/Album/src/AdjacentFolder?